# Mongoid map/reduce aggregates, but how do I access the full document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Receipe model, and I show all recipes in a feed.  There could be 5 instances in that feed of the "Mac & Cheese."  I want to group them all together and show the count next to "Mac & Cheese" in the feed.  That part I get.  There's more info from the document that I want to display related to the recipe such as who created it and when.  When I run Map / Reduce, I just get back the recipe name, and count, how do I access the last document in the group to display user_id and created_at and other document attributes?

```
class Recipe
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include MongoidVote::Voteable
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  field :name
  field :slug

  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :recipes

  def self.grouped
    map = %Q{
      function () {
        emit(this.name, {count: 1});
      }
    }
    reduce = %Q{
      function(key, values) {
        var result = {count: 0};
        values.forEach(function(value) {
          result.count += value.count;
        });
        return result;
      }
    }
    self.all.
      map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true)
  end
end
```

From the console, everything works as expected.

```
recipes = Recipe.grouped
recipes.each do |r|
  puts r
end

{"_id"=>"Mac & Cheese", "value"=>{"count"=>3.0}}
{"_id"=>"Spaghetti and Meatballs", "value"=>{"count"=>1.0}}
{"_id"=>"Egg Sandwich", "value"=>{"count"=>2.0}}
```

How would I go about accessing the full document and relations for each recipe to display username, recipe name, recipe count?  Do I need to loop through the results from Recipe.grouped and re-query for the full recipe document based on it's name or is there another way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> how do I access the last document in the group to display user_id and created_at and other document attributes?

If you only want the last `user_id` in all recipes with the same name, you could emit `user_id` in mapper and catch it in reducer.

mapper:

```
function () {
  emit(this.name, {count: 1, user_id: this.user_id});
}
```

reducer:

```
function(key, values) {
  var result = {count: 0, user_id: null};
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    result.count += value.count;
    result.user_id = value.user_id; // we only care about the last one.
  });
  return result;
}
```

In your case, it is better to use [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) introduced in 2.2. For most aggregation operations, the Aggregation Pipeline provides better performance and more coherent interface. The [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operation will do all you need. You could use `$last` to get the `user_id` and `$sum` to get recipe count.

In mongo shell, it looks like:

```
db.recipes.aggregate(
    { $group : {
        _id : "$name",
        count : { $sum : 1 },
        user_id : { $last : "$user_id" }
    }}
);
```

If you want all user_ids, `$push` is what you need.

Moped supports aggregation framework, according to this issue.
https://github.com/mongoid/moped/issues/49

> How would I go about accessing the full document and relations for each recipe to display username, recipe name, recipe count?

Since MongoDB and Mongoid support batch query with `$in` in the criteria of `find()`, once you have all user_ids, that's only one extra query.

It seems like only username is needed in your case, denormalizing `username` in recipe document is a good idea to save the extra query. It could be retrieved like `user_id` above in aggregation framework.

Comment: this is awesome, thank you.  I will update to 2.2 and try the aggregation framework like you suggested.  Ultimately what I was trying to determine if I used map/reduce, would I have to then perform another query to get the full document info.  It's not just user_id I need, I'd want to display a list of recipes and their ingredients which are in a sub-document to Recipe.  Sounds like I would have to do that, unless with map reduce, but perhaps not if I use grouping as a result of the 2.2 aggregation framework, correct?

Comment: If you only want the ingredients of the *last* recipe among all recipes with the same name, the answer is YES. But another way to think this problem is: what data do you think will be "aggregated"? If the only aggregated info is count, why not use findOne() and count() separately? Thus we don't need to retrieve all these document to get the count.

Comment: That's a great suggestion @visualzhou, thank you.  That's probably a much better way to approach the problem.